# Set form action with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, get

I have a basic form. I have hidden inputs outside the form. I want to set the form action with JavaScript to include the values from the hidden parameters as variables in the GET of the form when the user press the enter/submit button.

The form's current action is `"https://example.com"`. I want to use JavaScript to take the values from the hidden inputs and concatenate them to the form's action so that the information stored outside the form is submitted with the form.

For example, the desired output for the form's action would be `"https://example.com?firstParameter=parameter&secondParameter=secondParameter"`.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<form action="https://example.com" method="GET">

    <input type="text"></input>
    <button type="submit"></button>

</form>

<input type="hidden" id="firstParameter" value="parameter">
<input type="hidden" id="secondParameter" value="anotherParameter">

<script>
function setFormAction() {
    var firstParameter= $("#firstParameter").val();
    var secondParameter= $("#secondParameter").val();
    var url = "https://example.com?";
    if(firstParameter!== ""){
        url = url + "&firstParameter=" + firstParameter; 
    }
    if(secondParameter!== ""){
        url = url + "&secondParameter=" + secondParameter; 
    }
    // form action = url; (Need help here)
}

</script>
```

Comment: You are missing `()` next to `setFormAction`, should be `setFormAction() {}`

Comment: Also need a `?` for the search params in url

Comment: Ok. Also, is it possible to set the "action" in the form tag to a function which establishes what the action is? For example <form action="setFormAction()">?

Comment: Not quite like that but you can set it in a submit event listener

Comment: Or using JavaScript in the tag with "onsubmit="?

Comment: This is an unusual operation. Why are you needing to do all this in the first place? It's not uncommon to manipulate the `action` but simply setting the inputs in the form will take care of the search params for the url so long as they have a name

Comment: Hmm okay. I'll look into alternative ways to do this

Comment: I gave you a solution below that appends the inputs to the form that will effectively do what you are trying to do manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution might be to add `name`s to the hidden inputs then append them to the form so they get submitted by default process.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="firstParameter" name="firstParameter" value="parameter">
<input type="hidden" id="secondParameter" name="secondParameter" value="anotherParameter">
```

JS

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   const $form = $(this);
   $('#firstParameter, #secondParameter').each(function(){
       if(this.value){
          $form.append(this)
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate this answer, it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
document.querySelector('form').setAttribute('action', url);
```

```js
function setFormAction() {
  var firstParameter = $("#firstParameter").val();
  var secondParameter = $("#secondParameter").val();
  var url = "https://example.com";
  if (firstParameter !== "") {
    url = url + "&firstParameter=" + firstParameter;
  }
  if (secondParameter !== "") {
    url = url + "&secondParameter=" + secondParameter;
  }
  document.querySelector('form').setAttribute('action', url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://example.com" method="GET">
  <input type="text" />
  <button type="button" onclick="setFormAction()">Test</button>
</form>

<input type="hidden" id="firstParameter" value="parameter">
<input type="hidden" id="secondParameter" value="anotherParameter">
```

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in case of user input to sanitise it.

Comment: Is it possible to set the "action" in the form tag to a function which establishes what the action is? For example <form action="setFormAction()">

Comment: @SteveAlereza nope. You can so something like that with JavaScript libraries like React, Vue.js etc though

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid using form submission if you are not actually submitting a form in the general sense and use a simple button with an event to a function. You can then declare states which do different things with the submission like:

```
<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

```
let state = 'default'

function onFormSubmit()
{
   if (state == 'default') doDefaultThings()
   else doLessDefaultThings()
}

async function doDefaultThings()
{
   //collect necessary data
   let url = "https://example.com" //append here

   let res = await fetch(url)
   //do other things or redirect
}

document.getElementById('submit-button'
   .addEventListener('click', onFormSubmit)
```

Comment: I'm submitting the form with the enter button, I need to update the form's action to include the information outside the form when it is submitted

Comment: You can send the data using the fetch api for example. Makes for a more responsive UI. Forms are pretty old fashioned